# I have accidently install two versions of ubuntu and need to uninstall one of them

Tags: 14.04, uninstall

Somehow, I have managed to install 15.10 and 14.04 LTS along side windows 10. I am able to switch between all of them easily and with no problem but I would like to uninstall 14.04 LTS. I tried doing it through windows 10 with no success. I was wondering if there was a way I could uninstall 14.04 LTS using 15.10?

Comment: I have recently deleted Windows on my laptop and installed both Mint and Ubuntu to replace it. Mint is working perfectly, but not Ubuntu, so how can I clear it from the system, and then reinstall it?

Comment: Please ask a new question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you installed both on your machine in a disk partition and are running one of them through your linux live USB drive.

To remove 14.04, just format the partition where you've installed that version of Ubuntu (while you're on Ubuntu 15.10).

After formatting, you could merge that partition with another on your disk drive.

Comment: Thank you for the Info. Now 14.04 is still showing in the GRUB. I can't boot it but it's still there. Can I remove that?

Comment: Yes. Run 'sudo update-grub' on your Ubuntu 15.04

Comment: Yes it made perfect since. It was very easy to do.

Comment: now I have a different issue. every time I update my software it tells me to check my Internet connection. I click okay then it shows me all of the updates and I download them no problem. How do I fix that.

Comment: Stack Overflow's guidelines state that every new question should be created separately so that people who are facing the same problem as you in the future can easily find it. Make another question, and tag me in the comments if you like